# solve a simple append function using prolog language

Tags: prolog

when we make an append function in prolog, then I think this is the answer of that.

```
append([],L,L) 
append([H|T],L,[H|R]):- append(T,L,R).
```

but I don't have the clear meaning of it.please give me that. what's the meaning of the character "L"? purpose??? (append([H|T],L,[H|R]):- append(T,L,R). give me a discribtion to this line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your append predicate takes 3 arguments (`L1`, `L2`, `L3`):

```
append(L1, L2, L3)
```

Append tells you if `L3` is the list resulting from appending `L1` to the front of `L2`.

For the First case:

```
append([],L,L)
```

You give the base case for append (i.e. what is the result of the empty list appended to some list, `L`. The result is just the original list, `L`).

Your second case tells how you can prove some list `[H|T]` appended to the front of another list `L` to create some other list `[H|R]` where `H` is the head of the first input list and the resulting list.

```
append([H|T],L,[H|R]):- append(T,L,R).
```

The second part of this rule says that this is only true if one can prove that the list `R` is the result of appending `T` (the tail of the original input list) to `L`.